# What happen if two putitem event occur at the same time in dynamodb having same hash key and timestamp range key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a question 
If I am using dynamodb and I want to put item inside table where I am making hash key similar and for range key I am using current timestamp and if two or more event putitem at the same time then what would be the result. And I want all items to be updated. What can I do here.????

Answer (score 1):

**PutItem API - Two items having same hash key and range key:-**

1. The first request will create the item in the table
2. Second request will update (i.e. overwrite) the item on the table

**Update the items having the same hash key but different range key :-**

3. Firstly, DynamoDB doesn't allow to update multiple items in one API call
4. Second, you need both Hash and Range key to update the item
5. Steps - Get all the items for the hash key
6. Update the each item sequentially using update item API (or) use batchWrite item API to update all the items in one API operation. You can use `PutRequest` on [BatchWriteItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html) to update the item. The API documentation says that you can't update the item. It actually means that it can't be used to update the specific attribute in the item. It will **replace** the entire item. You should be ok as long as you have the full item data that needs to be replaced. As per the step 5 above, you should have the full item details (i.e. all the attributes in the item) that need to be updated (i.e. replace in case of batch write item)

Comment: As you have mentioned in pt. 3 . If the request comes from two different users at the same time and if hash key is same for this putitem and range key is current timestamp. Then what would be result here... Since both request comes  differently there will be not any API issue